# Firing a Journey Builder Event without using the API

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We are looking at the Entry Events for Journey Builder. Originally we set this up with an Automation (http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/how_to_fire_an_event/#FireEventAutoStudio). This worked successfully.

It looks like the Events can now be configured without an Automation in the Event Administration (http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/journey_builder_administration/event_administration/) on the Set Entry Schedule tab.

The client does not want to use the API.

My question is using an Automation or the Set Entry Schedule option, it looks like the subscriber can only be pushed into the Journey on a schedule. Using the API they can be pushed into the Journey immediately. Is quickest a subscriber can be pushed into a Journey (without the API) on an hourly basis?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can now define an Entry Schedule when configuring a Journey Builder Event instead of requiring an Automation with a single Event Activity. The minimum schedule for both the Event Entry and Scheduled Automations is one hour, however if you would like to increase this frequency, to say every 15 mins, then you could create a scheduled Automation that has a chain of Fire Event Activities and Wait Periods, for example:

[image: automation]

Comment: Man...there is always a way to get things done. Nice solution, thank you!